# Getting error while creating a new publication

Tags: 2013, content-manager

I set up a CMS on AWS environment and after that I created the publication, target groups, schema, components, pages, CT, PT etc. But after creating the first publication I am not able to create any more publications and getting the below error

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the setup, like is the database on the same server etc.?

Comment: Already disabled the firewall on database server, as the same error I initially got when I setup the CMS and that time I was not able to create anything in CMS but after disabling the firewall I was able to create everything. But now getting the same error while creating the publication.

Comment: @Bart: CMS and database are on different servers

Comment: If you run DTCPing (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2868) on both the Content Manager and Database servers is the connection successfully established?

Comment: also, please check the event viewer for additional errors on CM Server. it could be related to timeouts as well. Errors in GUI could be misleading sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the microsoft blog related to MSDTC and apply on both of your servers (CM server and DB server)

Comment: can you add the link to which blog you are actually referring? When I Google for "the microsoft blog related to MSDTC" I can't really find it easily, so your answer might be correct, but as it is, it is not really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

i had similar issue while installing 2011 sp1,(not AWS), following helped me to resolve the issue

http://oysterleelife.blogspot.in/2013/07/solved-communication-with-underlying.html.